# How do I install 3rd party libraries for an Angular 2 application using the ng-cli tool?

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap-3, angular-cli

There used to be this page https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/3rd-party-libs for installing 3rd party libs. It is no longer available. I was using `angular-cli: 1.0.0-beta.25.5` and this page helped me to install bootstrap.

Now, since I've upgraded to `@angular/cli: 1.0.0-beta.32.3`, and with this wiki page gone, I am wondering if the previous instructions no longer apply? Meaning, did ng-cli somehow managed to allow installation of 3rd party packages magically without manual user intervention.

I'd appreciate if someone may clarify why https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/3rd-party-libs no longer exists and how we are supposed to add 3rd party libs now (if those previous instructions are obsolete and where the new instruction is or how adding third party libs is supposed to happen).

For example, how would I go about adding popular third party libraries such as bootstrap or lodash using the latest ng-cli? If I recall correctly, lodash presents a problem in that it requires the installation of typings.

Comment: Not sure why there is a vote to close this question. From memory, I was able to add bootstrap manually by modifying angular-cli.json. I don't know why the page is removed if the previous steps are still required to add third party libs like boostrap and lodash.

Comment: Check under `docs`, specifically `docs/documentation/stories`

Comment: I think you should edit your question to make it more appropriate for this site.  Asking what happened to a certain wiki page on another site isn't really a programming question.  If you made the question more about what you were trying to do, like "How do I use bootstrap with angular-cli", people would be able to write a response and the question and answer would be more helpful to others.

Comment: @JasonGoemaat I need a real URL. I checked that directory and found nothing.

Comment: Not in the wiki, in the repository: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/tree/master/docs/documentation/stories